# How to use crosstab to display list of frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Hey i have data like this

```
[ID] [DATE]  [STOCK]
1 1/1/1 123
1 1/2/1 125
2 1/2/1 223
1 2/2/1 234
1 1/1/1 R123
```

I HAVE APPLIED CROSS TAB TO ID WITH DATE AND GOT THIS:-

```
train_ = pd.crosstab(train.ID, train.DATE)
[ID] [1/1/1] [1/2/1] [2/2/1]
1 1 1 1
2 0 1 0
```

I WANT OUTPUT TO BE LIKE

```
[ID] [1/1/1] [1/2/1] [2/2/1]
1 [123,R123] [125] [234]
2 [] [223] []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='DATE', values='STOCK')
print (df1)
DATE  1/1/1  1/2/1  2/2/1
ID                       
1     123.0  125.0  234.0
2       NaN  223.0    NaN

df1 = df.set_index(['ID','DATE'])['STOCK'].unstack()
print (df1)
DATE  1/1/1  1/2/1  2/2/1
ID                       
1     123.0  125.0  234.0
2       NaN  223.0    NaN
```

If there are duplicates in columns created new index and columns:

```
print (df)
   ID   DATE  STOCK
0   1  1/1/1  123.0<-same ID=1, DATE=1/1/1
1   1  1/1/1  200.0<-same ID=1, DATE=1/1/1
2   1  1/2/1  125.0
3   2  1/2/1  223.0
4   1  2/2/1  234.0
```

... then need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `apply` + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','DATE'])['STOCK'].apply(list).unstack()
print (df1)
DATE           1/1/1    1/2/1    2/2/1
ID                                    
1     [123.0, 200.0]  [125.0]  [234.0]
2               None  [223.0]     None
```

Replace `None` to `empty list` is not so easy:

```
a = [[[] for x in range(len(df1.columns))] for y in range(len(df1.index))]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(a, index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
df1 = df1.fillna(df2)
print (df1)
DATE           1/1/1    1/2/1    2/2/1
ID                                    
1     [123.0, 200.0]  [125.0]  [234.0]
2                 []  [223.0]       []
```

Comment: But Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Ok, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks! but i dont want to use aggregation function,if there is duplicate data  ->make a list and store